# how to use meta in scrapy rule

Tags: python, scrapy

```
def parse(self,response):
    my_item={'test':123,'test2':321}
    google_url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=coffee+cans'
    yield Request(url=google_url,callback=self.google,meta={'my_item':my_item})

def google(self,response):
    my_item = response.meta['my_item']
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="r"]/a',allow='/dp',allow_domains='chewy.com'),
            callback="chewy"),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="r"]/a',allow='/p/',allow_domains='homedepot.com'),
            process_request=request.meta['my_item']=my_item,callback='homedepot')
        )
def homedepot(self,response):
    #my_item = response.meta['my_item']
```

error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/timmy/.local/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 149, in execute
    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 251, in __init__
    super(CrawlerProcess, self).__init__(settings)
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 137, in __init__
    self.spider_loader = _get_spider_loader(settings)
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 338, in _get_spider_loader
    return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 61, in from_settings
    return cls(settings)
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._load_all_spiders()
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 47, in _load_all_spiders
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 71, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 674, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 781, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 741, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/timmy/scrapy_tut/myproject/spiders/amazon.py", line 62
    process_request=request.meta['my_item']=my_item,callback='homedepot')
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I edited the question to make more testable ,How can I pass `my_item` to the links extracted from `Rule(LinkExtractor...)` ( I moved the rules from the initialization of spider to make it easier for me to do (use meta) but I still can't do it.

Any help is much appreciated

I tried to use

```
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="r"]/a',allow='/dp',allow_domains='chewy.com'),
            process_request=lambda request:request.meta.update({'my_item':my_item}),callback='chewy'),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="r"]/a',allow='/p/',allow_domains='homedepot.com')
            ,process_request=lambda request:request.meta.update({'my_item':my_item}),callback='homedepot')

        )
```

This gives no error but the page isn't requested

Answer (score 2):

Your first example is wrong Python code, as Python reports.

Your second example does not work because your callback for the [`process_request`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.6/topics/spiders.html?highlight=process_request#scrapy.spiders.Rule) parameter of [`Rule`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.6/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Rule), the `lambda` function, returns `None`.

If you check the [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.6/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Rule):

> `process_request` is a callable, or a string (in which case a method from the spider object with that name will be used) which will be called with every request extracted by this rule, and must return a request or None (to filter out the request).

That is actually not the only reason it does not work. To use rule-based link extractors, you must:

- Subclass [`CrawlSpider`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.6/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider). From your examples it’s not clear if you are doing so.
- Don’t reimplement the `parse` method in your subclass, as you are currently doing. If `start_urls` is not good enough for you, use it in combination with [`parse_start_url`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.6/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider.parse_start_url).
- Rules must be declared as a [class attribute](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.6/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider.rules). You are instead defining them as a variable within a method of your Spider subclass. That won’t work.

Please, re-read [the documentation about the CrawlSpider](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.6/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider).

As for passing a value from the meta of a response to the meta of the next request, you have 2 choices:

- Reimplement your spider as a [`Spider`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.6/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider) subclass, instead of a [`CrawlSpider`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.6/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider) subclass, manually performing all the logic without rule-based link extractors.

  This is the natural step whenever a generic spider like [`CrawlSpider`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.6/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider) starts to feel too restrictive. Generic spider subclasses are good for simple use cases, but whenever you face something non-trivial, you should consider switching to a regular [`Spider`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.6/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider) subclass.
- Wait for [Scrapy 1.7 to be released](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/milestone/22), which should happen shortly (you could use the `master` branch of Scrapy in the meantime). Scrapy 1.7 [introduces a new `response` parameter for `process_request` callbacks](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/3682), which will allow you to do something like:

```py
def my_request_processor(request, response):
    request.meta['item'] = response.meta['item']
    return request

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    # …

    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="r"]/a',
                allow='/p/',
                allow_domains='homedepot.com'
            ),
            process_request=my_request_processor,
            callback='homedepot'
        )
    )

    # …
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the explanation, I don't believe crawl spider is an issue because even with your code it will not work (Spider) and `my_request_processor` item won't be defined in request or response. the only things I can access are link and test in (a or area) as they are defined as `scrapy.link.Link'` which contains text,URL fragment and follow. This one Scrapy developers need to work on, and since you're familiar I hope they also fix ItemLoaders to be passed around between responses directly (without manipulation)