# change response in scrapy itemloader

Tags: scrapy

Is there a way to change the response used in an `ItemLoader`, for example I am parsing two pages and I pass my_item in meta, the response in the item loader is the first one (where I initially defined it).
 I am currently using `my_item.add_value('price',response.xpath('//p[@id="price"]').extract_first()` to get passed this since I can't use `my_item.add_xpath('price', '//p[@id="price"]')` because the response is from the initial page

```
my_item = ItemLoader(item=MyItem(),response=response)
#fill my_item
yield Request(My_url,callback=self.parse_item,meta={'my_item':my_item)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
def parse(self, response):

    l = ItemLoader(item=YourItem(), response=response)
    l.add_xpath('Field1', '...')
    l.add_value('Field2', '...')

    item = l.load_item()

    yield scrapy.Request(
        url=another_url,
        callback=self.second,
        meta={'item': item}
    )

def second(self, response):

    l = ItemLoader(item=response.meta["item"], response=response)
    l.add_xpath("Field3", '...')

    yield l.load_item()
```

Comment: aha so I should load the item before I pass it to second function

Comment: @programmerwiz32 exactly

Comment: can you please check out this also [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56995150/how-to-use-meta-in-scrapy-rule]