# How to pass a variable from init to parse_item in Scrapy CrawlSpider?

Tags: python, scrapy

Maybe it's the wrong approach alltogether. I'd be happy about an alternative approach as well, if you have an idea.

1. Connect to my DB, get the next batch of seed URLs (as a dict, with some other info)
2. Add their URL/domains to `start_urls` and `allowed_domains`
3. With each request, I'd like to write some other info from the DB with the seed URLs to the yielded item

In a **Spider**, I'd simply use `meta`. But that won't work for a CrawlSpider.

```
class TestCrawlerSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'testcrawler'
    
    allowed_domains = []
    start_urls = []
    
    current_batch = None
    
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), process_request=my_request_processor, callback='parse_item', follow=True, process_links="filter_links"),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), process_request=my_request_processor, follow=True, process_links="filter_links"),
    )
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.current_batch = run_manager.get_next_batch()

        for doc in self.current_batch:
            self.start_urls.append(doc.get('website'))
            self.allowed_domains.append(doc.get('domain'))

        super(TestCrawlerSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        # how to access the current doc (from __init__) here?
        doc_id = doc.get('id')
```

I've tried [how to use meta in scrapy rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56995150/how-to-use-meta-in-scrapy-rule/57076321#57076321) but I still don't know, how to pass the data from `__init__` to the Rule.

Comment: How is it that you access meta from `__init__` in a regular scrapy spider?  The only thing I can think of would be to create an dictionary instance attribute with the start_request as keys and the extra information you want to include as the values, and then to simply grab the information using `response.url` in the `parse_items` method.

Comment: Sorry, yes - in a Spider, I'd retrieve the start urls inside the start_request method. In a CrawlSpider I don't have this method and used the __init__ for retrieving the start URLs.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  So does my suggestion make sense?

Comment: I was trying to avoid it, due to the need, to "calculate" the key for every request. I'm using the domain as a unique key in the list of dicts that you've indicated. In order to find the right one, I have to extract the domain from every response.url in every parse_item run. But yes - seems to be the way to go.